# C3 JS - time series tick reverses the format

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I've got a c3 time chart with the following config:

```
const labels = ['labels',
  ...map(
    (d) => d.format('L'),
    pluck('date')(data)
  )
]
const initial = [
  labels,
  [facetName, ...pluck('count')(data)]
]
const settings = {
  axis: {
    x: {
      tick: {
        multiline: false,
        rotate: 75,
      },
      type: 'timeseries'
    },
    y: {
      tick: {
        format: d3.format(',')
      }
    }
  },
  bar: {width: { ratio: 0.5 }},
  data: {
    colors: {x: 'rgb(185, 221, 147)'},
    columns: initial,
    type: 'bar',
    x: 'labels',
    xFormat: '%m/%d/%Y'
  },
  grid: {y: { show: true }},
  legend: { show: false }
}
```

Ideally, the labels should end up being displayed as `1/1/2000`. Instead, however, they are coming out as `2000/1/1`.  What am I missing in the formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Use the format option in the axis declaration instead.
http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-tick-format

i.e.

```
axis: {
    x: {
          tick: {
            multiline: false,
            rotate: 75,
            format: '%d/%m/%Y', // NEW LINE
          },
          type: 'timeseries'
        },
    ... etc
```

Comment: Doing so returns `failed to parse x '1/1/2000' to Date object.`

Comment: It's very sensitive to the format of the original data. Is it a date object that your pluck 'date' returns or a string, and in that case what format does it return? For a quick fix attempt, what happens if you comment out the original `xFormat` line?

Comment: The values returned from `pluck` are just strings in the format supplied: `1/1/2000`. Removing the `xFormat` while leaving the `format` on the tick also throws an error.